# Custom field in edit mode 

Tags: development, custom-field-types

I have created a custom field type. I have added the field in a list and added a new item through it. Display mode also shows the value perfectly. But when I edit that item and my field is in edit mode it is rendering as if it was getting rendered in new mode.

I have created a filtered lookup column that is two list boxes. Any idea where I am going wrong?

Comment: When you say you added a "custom field" does that mean Field Type, or does it mean you added a custom Site/List Column?

Comment: I am talking about custom Field Type over here...I have created filtered lookup column...

Answer (score 4):

You are creating a custom field type and control by the sound of it. So somewhere within the logic of your custom field control, you need to inspect the value of

```
this.ControlMode
```

This value will be an enumeration of SPControlMode and will tell you what mode the control is in.  Use this to control what is rendered for the control in what mode.

It would help if you posted a code sample of your control and how your custom field type is defined.

Comment: yah I am using that for checking the display mode or not....but the problem was in set method of my field..anyways thanks for replying..

Comment: If anyone runs into same situation lemme know...

Comment: Amit if you have found the problem then please share it.  You can answer your own question.